# IOS Parses PFLoginViewController didLoginUser Delegate is not being called when logging in via Facebook, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

This is a very strange problem because my Facebook login was working before I updated to Xcode 6 and iOS 8. To make this even more strange Twitter is working excellent but Facebook isn't calling the didLogin callback.

Here is what I am doing in my AppDelegate:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>
```

Then I setup Facebook & Twitter in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[Parse setApplicationId:PARSE_APPLICATION_ID
              clientKey:PARSE_CLIENT_KEY];

[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
[PFTwitterUtils initializeWithConsumerKey:TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY
                           consumerSecret:TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET];
```

After setting these up I setup my rootViewController like so:

```
self.welcomeViewController = [[ConfigViewController alloc] init];

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.welcomeViewController];
[self.navController setNavigationBarHidden: NO];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In the `viewDidAppear` of my `ConfigViewController` I do the following check:

```
// Force logout for testing
//[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] logOut];

// If not logged in, present login view controller
if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
    [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] presentLoginViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    return;
}

// Present UI
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] presentTabBarController];
```

At this point if the user is not logged in the following happens in `presentLoginViewControllerAnimated`:

```
// Customize the Log In View Controller
loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
loginViewController.delegate = self;
loginViewController.facebookPermissions = @[@"email",@"public_profile",@"user_friends"];
loginViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsTwitter | PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton;

// Customize the Sign Up View Controller
signUpViewController = [[SignupViewController alloc] init];
signUpViewController.delegate = self;
signUpViewController.fields = PFSignUpFieldsDefault;
loginViewController.signUpController = signUpViewController;

[self.welcomeViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Here the loginViewController is presented. If the user taps on the twitter button he will login without any trouble. If the Facebook button is tapped however, the Facebook confirm screen shows up, I hit ok, then it returns to my loginViewController. I need for this to be called:

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user
```

So that I can dismiss the loginViewController and also perform any additional actions. Any idea as to why this could be happening?

Again, Why loginViewController:didLogInUser: delegate not being called for Facebook?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

[EDIT]

After much testing and many headaches here is the latest on this.

If I screw up the `URL Schemes` in my Info.plist it works. I changed the name from `URL Schemes` to `URL Scheme` and I get the following error:

```
FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb6************** is not registered as a URL Scheme
```

Even though I get this error, I am getting a screen popup to log into FaceBook. I fill it out and I am in, it works, I can login with Facebook. This doesn't seem convenient but it is working.

Other tests/things I tried were downloading the Facebook app and trying to login, login without the Facebook app (through safari), implementing the delegates in my welcomeViewController instead of my AppDelegate, and updating Parse/Facebook SDKs.

I think the problem might have something to do with opening up another app such as Facebook or safari. The reason I am leaning towards this is because the twitter screen is a modally popped up view and it works without an issue. When Facebook gives me this error, it doesn't switch to safari or the Facebook app, instead it shows a modally popped up login and it works fine. This leads me to believe that the problem is related to switching apps and not receiving the callback properly.

I also have a third login option which I neglected to mention. This third option works just  by signing up without a social media account, and this is also working.

HUGE thanks to **Matt Tang** for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually logged in when it returns to your loginViewController? Implement logInViewController:didFailToLogInWithError: to see if that gets called

Comment: I have it implemented and it isn't getting called.

Comment: And you've implemented both in AppDelegate.m? Let me keep looking at your code.

Comment: I have actually implemented all Login callbacks and none are being called for Facebook.

Comment: Could you show all of your AppDelegate.m?

Comment: I can't post the entire thing sorry :( But if you have questions I can possibly answer them.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're making the AppDelegate the delegate for loginViewController and signUpViewController? Could you try making the welcomeViewController the delegate of each and moving the delegate methods to welcomeViewController?

Comment: I am going to give that a go. If that works I will let you know. How can I share my full AppDelegate.m with you? I tried to post it but it was too large according to SO. Maybe I will paste bin it in a little bit.

Comment: I just noticed that it was working before you updated to xcode 5 and ios 8. Maybe check to see if you have the latest version of the Parse iOS Library. I'm not sure why it would't work. Your code looks fine.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kdBKUYkS

Comment: I updated my frameworks and still nothing, I switched my handlers to the welcomeViewController and still same thing. ApplicationDidBecomeActive is the only thing being called after Facebook is confirmed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63296/discussion-between-matt-tang-and-pimentelk).

Comment: @MattTang I was finally forced to revisit this one and I was able to figure it out, I posted my answer on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had accidentally deleted/commented out portions of these 3 callbacks, this was the source of the problem. In the end, the solution for me was to implement `application:handleOpenURL:` and `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`

```
// Facebook oauth callback
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}
```

and to uncomment this line:

```
[FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
```

Which I had inside of this call back:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Comment: Nice. You figured it out

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason was switching to a testing FB app, where you need to change the appID. The requests then have different tokens, particularly the former token I used ( not the one generated after creating a test app on FB).

The solution for me was to delete the app from simulator and run it again.