# PFLoginViewController didLogin never called when logging in with Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I'm having the same problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444612/ios-parses-pfloginviewcontroller-didloginuser-delegate-is-not-being-called-when).  The solution that was eventually found was to break the URL Schemes in the plist file so that when logging in to Facebook you would never leave the app to go to Safari and would instead login through a web view within the app.  However, this seems rather inconvenient as it doesn't save user credentials like Safari does.

Why does the PFLoginViewController didLogin get called when facebook is loaded within a webview but not get called when facebook is loaded within safari and how can I fix that.  It's not just that it doesn't get called, but a user is not being created either as [PFUser currentUser] returns nil after loading facebook with safari.

Comment: I am still having this issue from the original thread I posted. I am going to revisit it within the next couple of days. I am going to take a deeper look at this issue. I'll be sure to let you know what I find!

Comment: I'll let you know if I figure anything out as well, but for the moment I'm gonna take a break.  Good luck!

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I've updated my post to contain an actual question.

Comment: I am working on this now, the only thing I've learned that I didn't notice before is that: If you go to settings > privacy > Facebook > App should be showing up here if it's requesting access to Facebook. My app isn't showing up on this screen so it isn't requesting access.

Comment: I figured it out for myself, I'll post the answer shortly. In short there are some callbacks in the `AppDelegate` that need to be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a doozy but it was actually an easy fix. I retraced my steps and realized I had accidentally deleted my call back methods. Here they are:

```
// Facebook oauth callback
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}
```

Give it a go, and let me know if this solves your problems. I am not 100% sure if this is the way to do it as I had an old deprecated example to look at. Here is the old deprecated way of doing this:

```
// Facebook oauth callback
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [PFFacebookUtils handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [PFFacebookUtils handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Handle an interruption during the authorization flow, such as the user clicking the home button.
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

Comment: I had implemented two of the methods but in a different way.  Using the top 3 callbacks you posted solves the problem though.  Thanks!